# How to find if an integer array has three integers which are same?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose we have an integer array numArray[10,23,47,10,19,10] and a number(k) 10, we need to find if the array has three of that number ( in this case, it does ). What is the best way to check this? The way I am thinking of right now is to sort the array and then look through the array if 3 of that numbers are adjacent to each other.

```
numArray = sort(numArray) // O(nlogn)
Loop through numArray to check if number ks are adjacent  // O(n)
```

which would give the total runtime to be O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn). Is there a better way to do this in lesser time?

UPDATE : How would the answer change if the number k is not given. Just find if any number occurs three times in the array?

Comment: Keep a counter, and iterate through the array incrementing the counter when you find a 10. O(n) time  O(1) space

Comment: Do you have a programming language you want this implemented in, or is this just an algorithm question?

Comment: It is basically algorithm question. If it helps, I am trying to implement this in C++

Comment: -UPDATE- pass `k` as a parameter to the function. Maybe next time mention the C++ need to get a proper language example.

Comment: Not slapping you on the wrist, but entering this: `c++ find occurences in array` as a google search term will bring you a lot of examples...

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with C++, but here is a Python solution for both if you know `k` and don't know `k`. The first is `O(n)` time-complexity with `O(1)` storage usage. The second is `O(n)` in both.

**Way 1**: Just count the number of occurances of `k` and check if count == 3, or any `n`.

**Way 2**: Create a dictionary/map of values to occurrences of that value. As you iterate over your values, increment the count for that value in the map. Then loop over the values in the map and check if the value is 3, or any `n`.

```
def array_contains_n_k(arr, n, k):
    count = 0
    for val in arr:
        if val == k:
            count+=1

    return count == n

def array_contains_n_number(nums, n): 
    counts = dict()
    for val in nums:
        key = str(val)
        if key in counts:
            counts[key] += 1
        else:
            counts[key] = 1

    for k,v in counts.items():
        if v == n:
            return True

nums = [10, 23, 47, 10, 19, 10]
k = 10
n = 3

print array_contains_n_k(nums, n, k) # True
print array_contains_n_number(nums, n) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the array is huge, you simply could convert the array to a string and count occurences of the number you are looking for (see snippet). I am not sure how this would work out with large arrays.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var numArray = [10,23,47,10,19,10];
    var mystring = numArray.toString();

    var count = (mystring.match(/10/g) || []).length;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = count;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">count 10's</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Just iterate through the array as is.. Too much overhead with strong in terms of space..

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RepeatedNumInArray {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 

           int arrynum[] = {10,23,47,10,19,10};

           for (int i = 0; i < arrynum.length; i++) {
            // put all integer values in Map
            // make use of Map key-value pair
               if(hm.containsKey(arrynum[i])){
                   hm.put(arrynum[i], hm.get(arrynum[i])+1);   
               }
            //if value occur only one time
               else
               {
                   hm.put(arrynum[i], 1);
               }
        }


        for(int i:arrynum)
        {  
          //check if value occurs 3 times
          if (hm.get(i) >=3)
                     {
  System.out.println("Repeated num in Array is " +i+ " : "+hm.get(i));
                 break;
                     }  
         }  

}

}
```

OutPut : Repeated num in Array is 10 : 3